# Centralized error handling for AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, block, centralized

I'm looking for a way to handle "generic" errors such as request timeouts or for when the connection goes offline.

Basically, I have multiple (singleton) subclasses of AFHTTPSessionManager where each one represents a *client* that handles requests to different servers. Each client is setup by overriding `initWithBaseURL` as recommended by the author of AFNetworking; this is where the request/response serializers as well as generic headers are set. Here's a sample client:

```
@implementation APIClient

+ (APIClient *)sharedClient {
    static APIClient *sharedClient = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedClient = [[self alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"baseurl.goes.here"]];
    });
    return sharedClient;
}

- (instancetype)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    self = [super initWithBaseURL:url];

    if(self) {
        // Setup goes here
        self.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
        self.requestSerializer.timeoutInterval = 20.0f;

        self.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"text/plain", @"text/html", nil];

        [AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager sharedManager].enabled = YES;

        [AFNetworkActivityLogger sharedLogger].level = AFLoggerLevelDebug;
        [[AFNetworkActivityLogger sharedLogger] startLogging];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)startPostRequestWithPath:(NSString *)path parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters successBlock:(APISuccessBlock)success failureBlock:(APIFailureBlock)failure
{
    [self POST:path parameters:parameters
       success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nonnull responseObject) {
           success(responseObject);
       } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
           if(isGenericError) {
               // Do something generic here
           }
           else {
               failure(error);
           }
       }];
}
```

Inside my model (e.g, Post), I have a static method that can be used by the view controller to fetch the data by passing its own success/failure blocks to the client. So it goes like this:

```
View Controller --> Model --> Client --> Model --> View Controller.
```

And here's the implementation of the model

```
@implementation Post

+ (void)fetchLatestPost:(void (^)(Post *parsedData, NSError *error))completion
{
    [[APIClient sharedClient] startRequestWithPath:kIndexPath
                                            parameters:nil
                                           requestType:RequestTypePost
                                          successBlock:^(id data) {
                                              NSError *parsingError = nil;
                                              Post *post = [[Index alloc] initWithDictionary:data error:&err];
                                              completion(index, nil);
                                          }
                                          failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                                              completion(nil, error);
                                          }
     ];
}
```

When a view controller tries to fetch that Post and the request times out, I'd like to hide the contents of the screen and show a refresh button; this logic is implemented in my BaseViewController so that all view controllers can reuse it. The question is, how do I restart the SAME request when that button is clicked? Do note that a view controller can make multiple requests from different models with different method signatures. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I can't seem to figure this out at all.

I used to handle this using delegates, where the BaseViewController would implement the "generic" delegate methods. However, I've been trying to switch to blocks and while it does have its advantages, it doesn't allow me to make use of my BaseViewController since it's can't "override" the view controller's failure blocks.

Comment: it can't override block, but super can supply a generic interface and wrap the child block

Comment: Not sure I'm following, how can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: for example, parent can provide a method, accept a block param, and return a block to instead of pass in failureBlock. so when fail, parent created block will be called, and than parent can determine how to call child block. Also, when create the parent block, you can pass additional param to make the block keep the request info for later reuse.